# bezier curve in objective c using coreplot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, bezier

i am developing one app in iPhone in that application i want smooth curve using core plot frame work.can any one suggest how to implement smooth curve

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A new interpolation mode, `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved`, was added after the 1.0 release. It will draw bezier curves between each point in the scatter plot. You can get support for it by pulling the latest code with Mercurial or wait for the next release.

Comment: Can you give me the link for latest code in which I can find this property ?

Comment: Instructions for pulling the code are at http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout . The Core Plot wiki has more info about using Mercurial http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingMercurial .

Comment: I checked out code from this and i got the latest version 1.0 only. in which there is no **CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved** property defined.

Comment: How did you pull the code? Make sure you update to the latest revision, not just the release 1.0 tag. You can see the current contents of the Mercurial repository online at http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/list